# How to span over variable number of cells?

Tags: tables, tabu, multicolumn

I'm looking for a macro to span all cells in a `tabu` environment to get category headers in tables.

This example does what I need for two columns.

```
\begin{tabu} {XX}
   abc   & def \\
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{category header} \\
   ghi   & jkl \\
\end{tabu}
```

What I want is a macro without the need to specify the number of columns. The category header should always span over all columns of the `tabu` environment.

I tried to access the `tabu@nbcols` constant but I've got no clue how to do that. These two don't work:

```
\multicolumn{\tabu@nbcols}{c}{header}
\multicolumn{\the\tabu@nbcols}{c}{header}
```

What I want could look like:

```
\begin{tabu} {XX}
   abc   & def \\
   \mycatheader{category header} \\
   ghi   & jkl \\
\end{tabu}
```

Comment: errr, can't you use `\noalign{\textbf{Header text}}`?

Comment: No, this breaks the layout and uses a wrong row height.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\def\mycatheader#1{\multicolumn{\tabu@nbcols}{c}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{tabu} {XX}
   abc   & def \\
   \mycatheader{category header}\\
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{category header} \\
   ghi   & jkl \\
\end{tabu}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've fast got it.

Your problem is the use of macro with @ letter, that is normally not allowed; you need to write `\makeatletter` to be able to use @ and `\makeatother` to make the situation normal again.

Here is what you can do:

In your preamble, define a new macro to access the number of columns:

```
\makeatletter
\edef\mycol{\tabu@nbcols}
\makeatother
```

And in a `tabu` environment:

```
\begin{tabu} {XX}
abc   & def \\
\multicolumn{\mycol}{c}{header}\\
ghi   & jkl \\
\end{tabu}
```

Your macro could be written like this:

```
\def\mycatheader#1{\multicolumn{\mycol}{c}{#1}}
```

Comment: Thank You for your quick reply, I didn't use edef, but makeatletter directly inside the tabu environment. And that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabu} {XX}
 abc   & def \\
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{category header} \\
 ghi   & jkl \\
\end{tabu}

\bigskip
\newcommand{\mycatheader}[1]{\noalign{\medskip\noindent\centerline{\textbf{#1}}\smallskip}}

\begin{tabu} {XX}
abc   & def \\
\mycatheader{category header}
ghi   & jkl \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer. Your mycatheader works in a very specific (well limited) way as it is not possible to use all of the tabu styling options.

But I have to admit, that it does, what I asked for above. :-)